# PHP 8.1.6, XAMPP -> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function grapheme_strlen()

Tags: php

PHP 8.1.6 does not find `grapheme_strlen()`. Any ideas why this happens?

Full error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function grapheme_strlen() in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\v5\inc\classes\Validation.inc.php:90 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\api\v5\tests\validation.php(14): Validation::fullname('ann') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\v5\inc\classes\Validation.inc.php on line 90
```

The function:

```php
    /**
     * Checks if a fullname is valid
     *
     * @param string $fullname
     * @return FullnameValidation
     */
    static function fullname(string $fullname): FullnameValidation
    {
        $min_length = 3;
        $max_length = 30;

        if (grapheme_strlen($fullname) >= $min_length) {
            if (grapheme_strlen($fullname) <= $max_length) {
                return FullnameValidation::ok;
            } else {
                return FullnameValidation::too_long;
            }
        } else {
            return FullnameValidation::too_short;
        }
    }
```

Google gives me exactly zero results. Seems like i'm the only person who ever had this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you need to install the intl pecl extension.  i am not a XAMPP person.  but if you ran:

```
php -m
```

you need to see the intl module to resolve your problem.